# Not showing my mobile device in eclipse but show in Window 8 (portable device part)

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, usb

My eclipse is not showing my Samsung galaxy y mobile device. I tried following:

1. update my usb drive
2. kill and start my adb
3. update my sdk tools

But, till now it is not showing in eclipse.

Previously it worked fine on the same system.

Comment: Have you make device's USB Debugging checked in developer option or in manage application setting

Comment: yes.. i checked it in my device